# InversifyJS - What is the difference between .to and .toService?

Tags: typescript, inversifyjs

I'm confused by the documentation, which states that `.toService(MyClass)` is used for transitive bindings. But in the examples shown, i can achieve the same thing using a regular `.to(MyClass)` as well.

https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/master/wiki/transitive_bindings.md

What is the concrete use case of `.toService()`?

Comment: one is https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/11339920aeae9acb3b8ee58a71cc298453c8f07a/src/syntax/binding_to_syntax.ts#L97 and the other is https://github.com/inversify/InversifyJS/blob/11339920aeae9acb3b8ee58a71cc298453c8f07a/src/syntax/binding_to_syntax.ts#L18

Answer (score 0):

You use  the **.to()** method is used when you are binding an interface or symbol to a concrete class.

```
container.bind(B).to(A);
```

For the **.toService()** method is used when you want to bind an interface or symbol to an already bound service in the container.  InversifyJS will not create a new instance, but will return the same instance that was bound to the original service.

```
container.bind(C).toService(B);
```

Comment: In other words, toService(B) should not work unless you've bound something else to B?

Comment: Yes it's a transitive type binding and as defined it allows as to declare a type binding that is resolved by a previously declared type binding.